# How to combine two string randomly in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, random

I want to combine two words to get a list of other words containing its letters.

examples:

input: Jack & Sara

output:    `jaca, jara, jacka, jacra, jsara, jacara, jackra, jasara, jackara, jacsara`

input: Sara & Jack

output:   `sack, sark, sarak, sarck, sjack, sajack, sarack, sarjack`

I want to take the chars of the two words **randomly** to create those lists

Comment: @FrankerZ no bro

Comment: Can you please explain better what your desire output? is 'jacksara' also possible?

Comment: your expected output doesn't correspond to any  known logic...

Comment: You can use lisp for that )

Comment: @DavidWinder no i want the script take the chars of the two words randomly to create those lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create random chars from the string to create new one you can concat the 2 string and run simple for loop to get it.

```
function randSubStr($s) {
    $output = "";
    for ($i=0;$i < strlen($s); $i++)
            if (rand(0,1))
                    $output .= $s[$i];
    return $output;
}
```

If you want to get list of those words without get the same one again you can use array like in this script:

```
$a = "jack";
$b = "sara";
$s = "$a$b";
$arr = array();
for ($j=0; $j< 10; $j++)
        $arr[] = randSubStr($s);
echo print_r($arr, true);
```